# Out of Bounds Exception, need advice

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, indexoutofboundsexception

I've read gone through the tutorials, so by all means, if you see something that I've done wrong here, please tell me so I can learn to better-participate on this site.

The getPerishedPassengers method  below is giving me an out of bounds exception. I have researched and researched, and I seem to be populating the array properly, and I don't know what is wrong with the method that I've created either. Could someone guide me in the right direction as to how to overcome this exception? Thank you folks!

Here's the main/method:

```
int passengerMax = 2000;
int passengerActual = 0;

//Create a 2D array that will store the data from the .txt file 
String[][] passengerData = new String[passengerMax][6];

//Constructor to read the file and store the data in the array
Titanic(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(file))) {

        //Conditional for reading the data
        while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {

            //tab through the data to read
        passengerData[passengerActual++] =     fileIn.nextLine().split("\t");
        }
    }
}

public int getTotalPassengers() {
    return passengerActual;
}

//Method for getting/returning the number of passengers that perished
public int getPerishedPassengers() {
    int count = 0;

    //For loop w/conditional to determine which passengers perished
    for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
        int survive = Integer.parseInt(passengerData[i][1]);

        /*The program reads the file and if 1, the passenger survived. If 0,
        the passenger perished. Conditional will add to the count if they 
        survived*/
        if (survive == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Here's the stacktrace I'm receiving. I can include the test code as well if you folks would like. Thanks in advance:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at titanic.Titanic.getPerishedPassengers(Titanic.java:66)
at titanic.testTitanic.main(testTitanic.java:68)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see above, the issue is in the line:

```
int survive = Integer.parseInt(passengerData[i][1]);
```

My best guess, lacking your input file, is that when you are reading the file, at least one line creates an array of length 0 or 1.  In all likelihood, if the last line of the file is an empty line, it would be this line which is causing your array out of bounds exception, as the split would create an array of length 0.  Another cause would be a line which lacks any tab in it at all (say a space instead of tabs, etc.) will create a length 1 array, of which passengerData[i][1] will not exist, only passengerData[i][0] will.

Assuming that your input file does not have any lines which are improperly formatted / lack the appropriate number of tabs, I would suggest changing this line in the file read loop:

```
passengerData[passengerActual++] =     fileIn.nextLine().split("\t");
```

to:

```
String incomingLine = fileIn.nextLine().trim();
if (null != incomingLine && !incomingLine.isEmpty()) {
    passengerData[passengerActual++] = incomingLine.split("\t");
}
```

Comment: That advice is great, it worked! The .txt file is formatted correctly, so your fix was pretty much it. The only issue now is that your code is not reading one item at some point. For example, when reading from the array, it would say there were 1310 people aboard the titanic, but your code only reads 1309. Any thoughts on why that would happen?

Comment: If you mean that passengerActual is only 1309, keep in mind that it started at 0, rather than 1, so 1309 is actually equal to 1310. [1 through 1309 + the 0th entry].

Comment: Right, that makes perfect sense. So to make it read 1310 vs. 1309, would I set the initial declared passenger actual to 1? It needs to read 1310 as one of the answers that the program provides is: "There were 1310 passengers aboard the titanic." Even though 1309 is really 1310 by means of code, it isn't the right answer for the question.

Comment: I would suggest against doing that, as then you would potentially introduce fence post errors elsewhere in your code.

To account for the fencepost issue, I would suggest adding an output method which accounts for the fencepost differential, and still use the 0 based index elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, I will give that a shot. Thanks for your help.